# How to remove inverted edges in undirected graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, rows, undirected-graph

I have a edge list as cell array
['a' 'b','c' 'b','b' 'a']

I have been trying to generate a graph in MATLAB using G=graph(s,t) but I get an error for duplicate edges which i figure is because of [a b] and [b a]. I am not able to remove those in my cell array.

How can I remove those?

Thank you.